# matlab nntraintool: Is it 10 hidden units or 10 layers?

Tags: matlab

What does the number (10) mean in the red rectangle shown below?

[image]

Is it 10 hidden units or 10 layers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means 10 hidden units.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the number of hidden neurons in the hidden layer

Comment: It looks like you're answering to the comment instead of answering to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).